# Standard ML Palindrome without reversing the list

Tags: sml, palindrome

I am new to SML and don't understand too about the syntax.

I am doing a practice on checking palindrome without reversing the list. Here is my code

```
fun symmetric(i,n,inlist) = 
if List.nth(inlist,i-1) = List.nth(inlist,n-i)
    then true
else
    false;

fun palindrome(n, inlist) = 
let 
    val i = ref 1
in
    while !i < n do (
        if symmetric(!i,!n,!inlist) = false
            then false
        else ()
        i := !i + 1
    )
    true
end;
```

I got errors in fun palindrome only, but can't fix it by myself.

Comment: "I got errors" is not a very useful error description, but an expression can't have both the type `bool` (`false`) and the type `unit` (`()`). You seem stuck in an imperative mindset; consider avoiding references and using recursion instead of looping.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. And now, I have finished palindrome with recursion only. I just started functional programming for few days only. Before, I work on Java, Ruby and other similar languages. Programming with ML is a very special experience for me.

Answer (score 4):

You can even make a palindrome checker without converting your string to a list:

```
fun palindrome s =
    let fun check i j =
            i >= j orelse
            String.sub (s, i) = String.sub (s, j) andalso
            check (i+1) (i-1)
    in check 0 (String.size s - 1) end
```

Here is some feedback for your code:

1. Naturally, consider using recursion rather than iteration.
2. A common problem for non-functional programmers is that they seem to want to execute many statements in succession only for their side-effect. In functional programming you rely very much on the value of every *expression* to guide the result of the program. There *is* a `;` operator, though, and it could be used like this:

   ```
   fun palindrome s =
       let val i = ref 0
           val j = ref (String.size s - 1)
           val result = ref true
       in while !i < !j do
              (if String.sub (s, !i) = String.sub (s, !j)
               then (i := !i + 1 ; j := !j - 1)
               else (i := !j ; result := false))
        ; !result
       end
   ```

   Often, though, if you want to do multiple things in a row, let-expressions are just as neat as the `;` operator.
3. The code

   ```
   if A = false
   then false
   else B
   ```

   can be written as

   ```
   if not (A)
   then false
   else B
   ```

   which can further be improved into

   ```
   if A
   then B
   else false
   ```

   which is really the same as

   ```
   A andalso B
   ```

   So the morals are:

   1. Instead of `A = false`, write `not A` (and instead of `A = true`, write `A`).
   2. You can always replace `if ... then <true/false> else <true/false>` with some combination of `andalso` and `orelse`. That is, *if-then-else* is never necessary when the result type is *bool* (but you might still prefer it if the logic is very convoluted).

Answer (score 3):

If the restriction against reversing a list was intended to ban using the built-in `rev` but not computations which implicitly reverse lists, here is a stack-based approach. The idea is to push characters onto a stack (represented as a list), and then pop them off, checking them against the original list of characters. If either the stack or the original list empty first, or if the item popped doesn't match the corresponding char in the original list -- it isn't a plalindrome

```
fun pushAll [] stack = stack
|   pushAll (x::xs) stack = pushAll xs (x::stack)

fun popCheck [] [] = true
|   popCheck [] _ = false
|   popCheck _ [] = false
|   popCheck (x::xs) (y::ys) = x = y andalso popCheck xs ys

fun palindrome s = 
    let val chars = explode s
        val stack = pushAll chars []
    in
        popCheck chars stack
    end;
```